# Update UserEntiy without changing password

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have User Entity for [user registration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security.html) on Symfony 4

I have User entity which has password.

Now I want to update some parts of row by Sonata Admin Bundle.

However it fails to update User entity because of there is no password.

in my UserAdmin.php

```
$formMapper->add('email');
$formMapper->add('nickName',null,array('required' => false));
$formMapper->add('enabled',null,array('required' => false));
```

I just want to change nickName or email without touching password.

in Entity I don't use validation, use `Assert` like this

`User.php`

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * The below length depends on the "algorithm" you use for encoding
 * the password, but this works well with bcrypt.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;
```

When registration, it works well like this in Controller.

```
$password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
$user->setPassword($password);

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: [Getting Started With FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844967/symfony-4-fosuserbundle > The Symfony Security component provides a flexible security framework
> that allows you to load users from configuration, a database, or
> anywhere else you can imagine. The FOSUserBundle builds on top of this
> to make it quick and easy to store users in a database, as well as
> functionality for registration, reset password and a profile page.

Comment: How exactly do you see that something is failing? Is there an error message given?

Comment: It can get tricky once you start to basically split up entities.  One reason I have moved away from the Doctrine ORM.  Bit extreme I know.  However, you probably want to take a look at [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html).  Groups will allow skipping the password validation stuff when necessary.  I don't use Sonata so I can't give you the specifics on how to specify a group but I am sure it is in the docs.

Comment: Are you sure you modified an existing User (iE loaded with `$repository->find($id)` and not created a new one?

Comment: @TsV I have used FOSUserBundle for my Symfony3 project. However I found that there is some difficulity FOSUserBundle with Symfony4. So now I try to use another way. It is true that FOSUserBundle works well for this kind of things though ...

Comment: @NicoHaase , I am sure the error is password validation.

Comment: @Cerad. thanks split up is good alternative way. At first I try to understand validation groups. It's a great step forward.

Comment: I am sure it doesn't create new one.

Comment: For now,  
I remove `* @Assert\NotBlank()` from 
   `/**
  * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     */
    private $plainPassword;` It might not good solution though.